# How to send awaited data from ViewModel to View in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

Xamarin.Forms (and C#) newbie here.

I found many answers on the subject of getting data from View to ViewModel, and then some on vice-versa. I feel a bit dumb, because I'm not getting it.

In my `LocationsViewModel.cs` a get some data of some locations from JSON API, then use that data to get `Xamarin.Essentials.Location` for each `LocationItem`, calculate proximity (distance) to device's `Location` and store that to `LocationItem.Proximity` for each item in `List<LocationItem> LocationsList`. All the methods used in this process are `async` and therefore `await`ed. My `LocationsList locations` is instantiated before any awaiting, so my View is loaded without errors, but because the awaited data is not then pushed to View the list of locations in the app is empty.

In XAML the `<ListView x:Name="LocationsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding locations}" ...>` is as you can see named, but that name is only available in View and not the ViewModel. How do I send it to View, so I can use something like `LocationsListView.ItemsSource = locations.Locations`?

##### LocationsViewModel.cs

```cs
using ...

namespace XXX.ViewModels
{
    ...

    class LocationsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private Location deviceLocation;

        public LocationsList locations;

        ...

        public LocationsViewModel()
        {
            Title = "Lokacije";

            RunAsyncMethods();
        }

        private async void RunAsyncMethods()
        {
            locations = await FetchLocationsJson();
            deviceLocation = await FetchDeviceLocation();
            locations = await SortLocationsByProximity(deviceLocation, locations);
            // The following fails since LocationsListView is unavailable
            // LocationsListView.ItemsSource = Locations.Locations; // This fails
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

##### LocationsPage.xaml.cs

```cs
using ...

namespace XXX.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class LocationsPage : ContentPage
    {
        MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
        public LocationsPage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, true);
            InitializeComponent();
            NetworkAccess current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
            if (current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                gridNews.RowDefinitions[0].Height = 0;
                gridNews.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
            }

            goToLandingPage.Clicked += GoToLandingPage;
            closeApp.Clicked += CloseApp;
        }

        private async void GoToLanding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await RootPage.NavigateFromMenu((int)MenuItemType.Landing, "", 1).ConfigureAwait(true);
        }

        private void CloseApp(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

##### LocationsPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:XXX.ViewModels"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:XXX.Models"
             x:Name="LocationsXaml"
             x:Class="XXX.Views.LocationsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:LocationsViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>


    <Grid x:Name="gridNews">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--#region (either) VIEW NO CONNECTION-->
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
                     x:Name="lblNoConnection"
                     ... >
            ...
        </StackLayout>
        <!--#endregion-->
        <!--#region (either) VIEW LOCATIONS-->
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  x:Name="LocationsListView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding locations}"
                  ...>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout ...>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                                       .../>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Proximity}"
                                       .../>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <!--#endregion-->
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

##### LocationItem.cs

```cs
using ...

namespace XXX.Models
{
    public class LocationItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("zip")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("city")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        public double Proximity { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocationsList
    {
        [JsonProperty("locations")]
        public List<LocationItem> Locations { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: use data binding - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/

Comment: Thank you @Jason . This will surely help the smart people.

Comment: For the time being I just moved the entire code from VM to V. It feels (and is) wrong, but hey ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it works.

Comment: to start with `locations` needs to be a **public property** in order for data binding to work.  You don't need to directly set `ItemsSource` from the VM, you just need to update the VM property that it is bound to.

Comment: But... `public LocationsList locations;` is that not a public property? And this `locations` property is updated inside `RunAsyncMethods()` method. What am I missing?

Comment: that is a field, not a property.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: My bad for not knowing the difference. Came from PHP where there is no such differentiation, I think (hope ), only properties and methods.